# Баг при изменении размера карты Google

Tags: google-maps-api

Стандартным способом выводится карта Google в `<div>` с `heigth = 40%`. Затем, нажатием на неё, она растягивается на весь экран (`heigth = 100%`), но данные для неё выводятся на всё те же 40% её высоты...

Как заставить их грузиться на всю высоту?

Код:

```
<div id="map1" class="mapstep2" style="height:40%; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 10px;"></div>

<script async defer
 src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&callback=initMap">
</script>

var y = 0;
function initMap() {
var mapOptions1 = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: coords,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    draggable: false,        
}
var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), mapOptions1, optnavigateonline);
 google.maps.event.addListener(map1, "click", function (event) {     
    if (y == 0) {           
        map1.setOptions({ draggable: true });           
        $("#map1").css({ "height": "100%" });
        scroll_to_elem("map1", 10);
        y = 1;
    } else
    {
        if (y==1)
        {
            map1.setOptions({ draggable: false });
            $("#map1").css({ "height": "40%" });
            y = 0;             
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызовите в нужном месте:

```
 google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо!